# 爱、采 ( A trivalent verb takes 2 objects )

Tags: usage, syntax

(my 1st post)

Could someone give me a sample sentence containing
爱 taking 2 objects?

I'm guessing it's    <<  I'd love him to [do ...] >>
type of construction?  Thank you.  HH

(from Wikipedia)
一价动词：强制要求与一种性质的名词性词语关联的一类动词。可记为动1。例如“病、醉、休息、游泳”等。这类动词差不多就是一般说的不及物动词。

二价动词：强制要求与两种性质的名词性词语关联的一类动词。可记为动2。例如“爱、采、参观、讨论”等。这类动词差不多就是一般说的及物动词。

三价动词：强制要求与三种性质的名词性词语关联的一类动词。可记为动3。例如“爱、采、参观、讨论”等。这类动词差不多就是一般说的双宾动词。[1]

Comment: text copied from Wikipedia has an obvious error, namely  the examples for divalent (transitive) verbs are repeated for the trivalent (ditransitive) case, for correct examples of trivalent verbs see English version, or use 给 （他给母亲一个礼物），告诉（妹妹告诉哥哥一个消息），花（这个事情花了他很多时间）

Comment: Thank you so much.     I can stop wondering now, and assume that 爱 and采 generally are not trivalent and do not take 2 objects.      In slang English, ppl say e.g.    [ I'll eat myself some supper.]  making "eat" trivalent.      Perhaps similar things exist in slang Chinese.

Answer (score 1):

**一价动词**(动1):

This is intransitive verbs, which means, verbs that cannot have an object attached to them.

Example: 我病了。 -> I am sick. (No object and cannot have an object)

**二价动词**(动2):

This is transitive verbs, verbs that can have objects attached to them.

Example: 我爱你。 -> I love you. ("you" is the object)

**三价动词**(动3):

Also called 双宾动词 and 授与动词，meaning verbs that can have *an object* and *a receiving or benefiting target*(i.e. equivalent to "to" in English or 给 in Chinese).

Example: 我送了礼物给我哥哥。 -> I gave presents(object) TO my brother(benefited target).

Comment: ditransitive or trivalent (having valency 3) means 2 objects follow verb immediately w/o any intervening preposition (coverb) so that possible example for 送 might be 我送了我哥哥一个礼物